# Performing a Response.Redirect from a non-Web based project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a utility method that contains some try/catches in it.  In those try/catches I need to redirect the customer using an HttpResponse redirect.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this outside a web project.  This utility class is referenced from my ASP.NET web project and so I'm just abstracting out some of the code into this utility class so I no longer have the request object.

I know I can use `HttpWebRequest` object for a lot of web related request tasks outside a web project, but could not seem to get any redirect method there to use after putting in a `using System.Net;` in my utility class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top of your file:

```
using System.Web;
```

In your function:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.com/redirect");
```

This way **does** make your library dependant on the `System.Web` library, but your code isn't in a web project. It will grab the current `HttpContext` for the request it's called from. You'll probably want to do some null checking though, if this code is called from outside of a web-context you're going to get a `NullReferenceException`.

If you're using WCF there's a different context-object you want to use, I just can't remember what it is. `OperationContext` maybe?

Comment: "This way does make your library dependant on the System.Web  library" so what's wrong with that?  simple using statement at the top, why would that hurt anything, that's just a native .NET namespace

Comment: @coffeeaddict some people don't like their libraries being dependent on too much. It's just something to take into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Why not pass the HttpContext into the Utility method?

Comment: A alternate form is you could have a redirect delegate defined by your utility class that is passed via parameter (or even an event). Then your utility method just calls the delegate internally if it was passed and does not need to have any knowledge of web, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general I try to keep dependencies like these out of Utility classes.  Refactor your utility method so it returns some indication to the caller to redirect to a different location.

for example, using a `AuthenticateResults` enum

```
AuthenticateResults Authenticate(string username, string password)
```

then perform your redirect based on the return value.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to think about how effective this would be in my existing code though...

Comment: I guess  I don't see how that dependency is an issue here.  You just add a namespace from the .NET framework...not a biggie.

Comment: it's just good OO design.  I'm not sure what you method does, but I'd guess it shouldn't know anything about HttpContexts.  plus, it's nearly impossible to test methods that call statics, much less statics that can't be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing your utility method from a web based project (so it has context), you can use:

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Redirect("{url-to-redirect-to}");
```

Comment: this utility method as I stated is now in a non-web based project with other Web Utility classes...so I don't have the context with me.

Comment: I guess I'll just pass the context into my utility method then...thanks

Comment: @coffeeaddict HttpContext.Current is a static member that always has the current context. When your utility code is loaded into a thread that was a result of a WebRequest, HttpContext.Current will provide the current context. That being said, I believe injecting the dependency via method or constructor paramater is FAR better than use HttpContext.Current

Comment: what do you mean injecting the dependency via method..you mean the CurrentContext and passing it as a param to my Utility method like I said?

Comment: oh so you are saying no need to pass in the current context as a param, it's there already because the thread caller was from the web project thread and so the context will be there and all I have to do inside my method is reference it by HttpContext.Current ..no need to do an extra passing in...